# Map key generate issue on android

Tags: android, android-emulator

i get knowledge from http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android.

i get fingerprint key from my machine.

I use below command :

keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "D:\Android\Key Store\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):     FB:8E:56:83:06:C6:AA:39:56:A8:04:DD:0F:ED:3E:71:BD:8A:3A:4A

But when i put on google map api, it throws "The fingerprint you entered is not valid. Please press the Back button on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint. "

If i give "FB:8E:56:83:06:C6:AA:39:56:A8:04:DD:0F:ED:3E:71" only google generate Map key. But its not woking on my device.

pls help me wtats the problem and how to generate map key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With  Windows 7 installed, keytool outputs by default`SHA1` fingerprint, not MD5. Adding -v option allows to see `MD5` as well.

```
list -alias androiddebugkey 
keystore "C:\android\debug.keystore"

storepass android -keypass android
```

-v for verbose..

All the best